# Foreground processes in Android

Tags: android

With respect to Process lifecycle, Android system tries to maintain an application process for as long as possible, but eventually needs to remove old processes to reclaim memory for new or more important processes. To determine which processes to keep and which to kill, the system places each process into an "importance hierarchy" based on the components running in the process and the state of those components. Processes with the lowest importance are eliminated first, then those with the next lowest importance, and so on, as necessary to recover system resources.

One of the classification is :

**Foreground Process :** A process that is required for what the user is currently doing. A process is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following conditions are true:

`1. It hosts an Activity that the user is interacting with.(the Activity's onResume() method has been called).`

`2. It hosts a Service that's bound to the activity that the user is interacting with.`

`3. It hosts a Service that's running "in the foreground" —the service has called startForeground().`

`4. It hosts a Service that's executing one of its lifecycle callbacks (onCreate(), onStart(), or onDestroy()).`

`5. It hosts a BroadcastReceiver that's executing its onReceive() method.`

What can be real life examples of scenarios given above I am asking this because it will help me and others as well in differentiating between this situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)THe app that is currently on top of the stack (the one the user is using)

2)An app with an Activity that has called bindService on any service.  The idea is that if it killed that service, it might lose data.  An example of this would be a facebook app, which has a background service to fetch data every so often.  If the user has it open, it would qualify

3)This is a service that has declared that its feeds data to a UI.  An example of this would be a facebook app where the user didn't have an activity with it open

4)This is a service that's just starting or just finishing.  This would be pure luck to have happen, but its basically saying it will try to let it start up or finish cleanly before killing it

5)This is any app that's currently responding to an event.  An example would be an SMS app that was just notified of an incoming SMS and needs to deal with it.  It will be allowed to run until its done, because doing otherwise may lose data.

Comment: thanks @Gabe this provides fair clarity to my doubts